# Retrieving and storing V8 object in void * for Node.js Addon

Tags: c++, c, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I’m trying to store an object passed from JavaScript to a Node.js Addon in a `void *`. I can’t seem to get this to compile; building with node-gyp produces `error: no matching function for call to 'Cast'`.

The long version of what I’m trying to do is write a Node.js Addon that runs Csound. Csound works, from a bird’s-eye view, with C functions that take a pointer to an opaque Csound struct as (usually) the first argument. This struct contains a `void *` to “`hostData`”, arbitrary data set by a program hosting Csound. Some things that Csound does, like posting messages, are modified with callbacks—function pointers in this case. I need a place to store callbacks for each instance of Csound, so I’m trying to let someone set `hostData` to an object from JavaScript, but I also want to set the callbacks for a Csound instance as [hidden properties](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Object.html#a0040e3012d621b25f580407bacebf95f) on this `hostData` object.

I think the code will need to look something like

```
#include "csound.h"

#include <node.h>

static void CsoundMessageCallback(CSOUND *Csound, int attributes,
  const char *format, va_list valist)
{
  // Call the JavaScript function we stored in the hostData of Csound.
}

static void _wrap_csoundSetMessageCallback(
  const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
  v8::HandleScope scope(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent());

  CSOUND *Csound;
  // Pretend we get the Csound instance from args[0] here. This is actually done
  // by SWIG <http://www.swig.org>.

  // This does not compile. csoundGetHostData() returns a void *, but I’m assuming
  // hostData was set to an object from JavaScript.
  v8::Persistent<v8::Object> hostData =
    v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::Cast(csoundGetHostData(Csound));

  hostData.SetHiddenValue(
    v8::String::New("CsoundMessageCallback"),
    v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::Cast(args[1])
  ); 
  csoundSetMessageCallback(Csound, CsoundMessageCallback);
}
```

I’m guessing I need to take a close look at V8’s internal fields, but I’m really not sure.

Comment: It's probably safer to just signal the main thread (e.g. using `uv_async_send()`) and execute the JavaScript callbacks from there.

Comment: I agree, but don’t I still need to store the callbacks that come in from JavaScript somewhere? Another thought I had was wrapping the Csound struct in a C++ class and storing the callbacks as member variables, but if it’s possible to use Csound’s `void *` `hostData`, I figure I might as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically what I've done in situations like this is I write a wrapper C++ class (inheriting from node's ObjectWrap class) that stores a pointer to the instance of whatever C/C++ class I'm wrapping and has various public methods to interact with that instance.

When `new` is called from JS land, a new instance of the wrapper C++ class gets created and associated with the new JS object. Then you have JS functions that kick off whatever async tasks that utilize the wrapped library's callbacks.

From there it's just a matter of calling `uv_async_send()` from the wrapped library's callbacks to signal the main thread and then calling the JS callback from the uv_async callback.

You can see an example of all of this [here](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc) (especially in the Windows-specific parts):

- The `Pcap` class holds a `pcap_t` pointer (would be a `CSOUND` pointer for you).
- When a new `Pcap` is created from JS land, I [wrap a new C++ class instance](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L216-L217).
- [Initialize a `uv_async_t`](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L399-L403) which sets up [the callback](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L152-L175) to fire on `uv_async_send()` and also [associates the user data pointer](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L403) to the class instance for easy access. You could do this initialization during the call to `new` if you wanted, instead of a separate prototype function (`open()`) like I have done since initialization just happens once.
- Then from [the wrapped library's callback](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L176-L181), I [signal](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L179) the main thread.
- From the uv_async callback, I can then [access the wrapper class instance](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L157) and use V8 functions safely. Although in my particular case, I have [another](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L168) [callback](https://github.com/mscdex/cap/blob/8cdd7712dda730e0436c070e7f88429b3541216b/src/binding.cc#L123-L148) which uses V8 functions. However you can use them safely inside your uv_async callback.

As far as storing JS callbacks goes, there are different ways to handle that. One solution might be to create a baton object that stores a Persistent copy of the JS callback and the wrapper class instance and store that baton in `uv_async_t`'s user data pointer. This would mean creating a new `uv_async_t` for every request (which is different than the example I gave above).